# GRASS r.out.png null values

Tags: grass-gis, export

'NV' cells in a raster layer appear to be exported to a .png as transparent (i.e. white), despite being recoloured in GRASS. Is there any way to force the cells to keep their colour?

Edit: A workaround is to open the .png in paint and fill in the null values manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your cell values, you could use r.null to assign values to null cells. This would enable r.out.png to colour the "null" cells.

An example implementation would be if your values are between 0 and 1, you could assign null cells to 1.0001 (or similar to not change the colour gradient) then set these 1.0001 cells to a specific colour in the 'set colour table [interactively]' GUI.